# I want to detect the name and color of the stuff I'm holding. But I can't. Please help me

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

```
/execute if entity @a[nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:netherite_sword",tag:{display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"asd\",\"bold\":true,\"color\":\"white\"}"}}}}]
```

I want to detect the name and color of the item I'm holding. But for some reason, it doesn’t work. Any ideas?
I’m playing Minecraft 1.16.4.

Comment: Hi lunia4582 and welcome to Gaming Stack Exchange. I assume this question is about Minecraft commands, but I am not sure. If that is the case, please tag the question with the minecraft-commands tag and the appropriate minecraft edition, such as minecraft-java-edition.

Comment: Thank you. I must have made a mistake. I'm sorry.

Comment: Is this command block looping?

Comment: Can you give the nbt of the item you are trying to detect?  You can do that by holding the item in your hand and then running the command `/data get entity @s SelectedItem`. This will really help your case as ExpertCoder14 said “So you need to check that your JSON source are exactly the same in the check and the item.”

Comment: /data get entity @s SelectedItem This way you can understand.Thank you very much.

Comment: have a good day ^.^

Answer (score 1):

Your command looks correct. It’s probably something with your setup.

Here is a very common problem with your setup that you should consider taking a look into.

When checking if the item’s custom name matches the one in NBT, the system is performing a plain text check of the raw JSON text *before* it is interpreted. It does not care about what the text looks like after it is interpreted. So you need to make sure that your JSON source are exactly the same in the check and the item.

The easiest things to mess up are spacing and order.

- Spacing: Make sure that extra spaces are the same in both references. So, the following examples render the same, but are considered different:

  ```
  {"text": "Test"}
  ```

  and

  ```
  {"text":"Test"}
  ```
- Order: Make sure the order of components is the same. The following two examples render the same, but are different:

  ```
  {"text":"Test","color":"white"}
  ```

  and

  ```
  {"color":"white","text":"Test"}
  ```

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll try to get it in.

Comment: Thank you for letting beginners know kindly.

Comment: have a good day ^.^